# Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I found solution to this problem.

The issue was due to the self signed certificate which I was using for the SharePoint site. When I used the certificate issued particularly to my SharePoint site it worked without any errors.

i saw your solution for the below thread
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/1a32b892-08c6-43e7-b988-667fc6ef1aa3/https-sharepoint-site-with-https-provider-hosted-app-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Can you please explain more details about the solution you provided
because i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

In most of cases the issue is, if you are using a self-signed certificate that has not been placed in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Store or ‘SharePoint root authority’ certificate is missing from the ‘Trusted Root Certificate Authorities’ container.

Once you add the cert in the store or via central admin of sharepoint, then it will fixed.

read more here: http://blog.gavin-adams.com/2015/07/01/sharepoint-2013-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssltls-secure-channel-with-authority/

Comment: New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Name "AppName" -Certificate $certificate if you run the above command automatically your certificate placed in central admin -Manage Trust  it is fine for my case. and i followed below steps to validate my apps    http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/12/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-provider-hosted-apps-on-premises/  but still getting same error if i give Tokenhelper.TrustAllCertificate() in my page load its working .

Comment: My Environment has 2 WFE  servers 1 App Server 1 DB Server now VS2012 is installed in 1 WFE server and i followed all my steps in WFE server where VS 2012 installed.and copied my Certificates in All other Servers as well but still getting same error.if i handle the certificate validation error in server side its working.but what steps i am missing probelm with "mysiteurl"//_vti_bin/client.svc webservice response only.if certificate validation fails it does not work

Comment: https://lennytech.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/powershell-install-sp-root-cert-to-trusted-root/    i checked this url also it says certificate already in trusted root authrority.   https://guybachar.wordpress.com/2014/05/28/find-certificates-that-are-put-in-the-trusted-root-certification-authorities-store-incorrectly-on-the-local-computer/    my question is Central admin my certificate avaialble and local trust Root Authority also contains my certificate and followed the validations steps but still getting same error. can you help me to solve this issue with any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a certificate to your SharePoint site, you have to the add the certificate **root** to the SharePoint Trusted Root Certificate Authority in your Central Administration; [check this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/add-certificate-to-the-sharepoint-trusted-root-certificate-authority/)